# Camel application is taking more than one hour to start

Tags: jboss, apache-camel, apache-karaf, jbossfuse

We're using apache camel with JBOSS fuse in our application for integration. We have build almost 80 APIs under one bundle and camel context contains 100+ routes.

When we deploy the bundle on JBOSS fuse, it takes almost 1 hour for all routes to UP and running and bundle gets "started" after 1 hour of deployment.
We could have divided our bundle into parts, lets says each bundle with maximum 10 APIs but we have already developed our application in one bundle and it's consuming so much time for starting.

Is there any way to reduce the time for the bundle to be "started" other than splitting the bundle into smaller bundles?

Comment: Why would you want to create such a large bundle?

Comment: That's the problem, we don't want to but the bundle is already created. We want to reduce the time it is taking to get "started".

Answer (score 0):

**First it should be noted-- this is an anti-pattern and should never be repeated (*looking at you Camel developer who just Google'd and found this article*).**

Karaf / JBoss Fuse can definitely scale to 100's of routes per instance (I've successfully run up to 500 in a single instance), but putting 100's of varying routes in one bundle is not advised-- ever. You lose a whole lot of process control, startup ordering management, and flexibility in adjusting your deployments to multiple containers as-needed.

You would need to look into some sort of async startup of the routes. The bundle won't go active until all OSGi components are active (including bundle activators, spring descriptors, scr components and blueprint descriptors).

If your routes are JMS consumers, look into the 'asyncStartListener' and 'asyncStopListener' options.

Another option is to disable starting the routes at bundle activation time, allow the bundle to go active and then have another process come through (in a threaded approach) and start calling route.start() on the all your routes.

[Camel JMS Component](http://camel.apache.org/jms.html)

[Camel Startup ordering](http://camel.apache.org/configuring-route-startup-ordering-and-autostartup.html)

Comment: We're using various camel components, File (15-20 routes), JMS (7-8 routes), and approx 100 routes for cxf:rsserver (15 cxf:rsserver endpoints and each having approx 6-7 routes on average).

Comment: Yikes. Probably your best shot is to configure all the routes to not start on startup and have another process come by and start them up-- however, if you are touching the routes anyway-- why not spend the time to separate them and deploy them as a feature?

Comment: Thank-you Matt, my question was the same - is there any workaround to start the bundle faster other than splitting it. I think splitting would be the right thing to do.

Comment: Yes.. review my response and the links I provided. Configure the routes not to start and then have a process that starts them up once the bundle is active